# Exponential PDF, infinite bounds

Tags: integration, probability-theory

#### The Question

Let $f(x, y) = e^{-x-y}$, $0 < x < \infty$, $0 < y < \infty$, $0$ elsewhere, be the probability density function of $X$ and $Y$. Then if $Z = X + Y$, compute $\Pr(Z \le 0)$, $\Pr(Z \le 6)$, and, more generally, $\Pr(Z \le z)$, for $0 < z < \infty$. What is the probability density function of $Z$?

#### My Attempt

I started by setting up the double integral

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^ \infty e^{-x-y} \, dx dy + \int_0^\infty \int_0^ \infty e^{-x-y} \, dy dx$$

But this doesn't look correct (and may not even be integrable). I suspect the integrals done for $X$ and $Y$ are basically the same but in some way have $X$ and $Y$ swapped in each, but I could be wrong. (As a side note, I do not believe this problem involves a transformation, as bivariate transformations are not discussed until the next chapter of the book.

If it helps, the book provides $ze^{-z}, \quad 0 < z < \infty$ as the solution, presumably for the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be the sum of two integrals. If we are looking for $P(Z \leq z) = P(X+Y \leq z)$ then we have the condition that $x+y \leq z$ or equivalently $0 \leq x \leq z - y$.

Then our bounds of integration become

$$
\int_0^z \int_0^{z-y} e^{-x-y} dx dy.
$$

This should be straightforward to integrate if you are comfortable with double integrals.

Comment: The limits for the outer integral should be $0$ to $z$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z >0$,$P\{Z \leq z\}=\int_0^{z} \int _0^{z-x} e^{-x-y} \, dy\, dx=\int_0^{z}e^{-x}(1-e^{x-z})\, dx=1-e^{-z}+ze^{-z}$. Differentiate to get the density.